# Assign JSON array to multiple select box with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, select

I am sending a PHP array via AJAX to a json array. The PHP array is a multidimensional array and is the same in JSON. How can I assign that array to a multi-select select box? I am using the code below and although JSON gets the array and assigns it to the individual edit box on the html page. Everything works except for towns, which is a multidimensional array and edit_town is a

```
  // JSON CODE:
  // Edit an existing attorney:
$("input[name='editAttorneyBtn']").click(function() {

    var providerID = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.post("www/scripts/ajax/getAttorney.php",{id : providerID},function(data) {
        if(data.response == true) {
            var info = data.info;
            $("input[name='edit_name']").val(info.name);
                            $("input[name='edit_attorney']").val(info.attorney);
                            $("input[name='edit_telephone']").val(info.telephone);
                            $("textarea[name='edit_attorney_description']").val(info.description);
                            $("textarea[name='edit_attorney_description']").ckeditor(ckConfig);
                            $("input[name='edit_fax']").val(info.fax);
                            $("input[name='edit_email']").val(info.email);
                            $("input[name='edit_physical1']").val(info.physical1);
                            $("input[name='edit_physical2']").val(info.physical2);
                            $("input[name='edit_physical3']").val(info.physical3);
                            $("input[name='edit_town']").val(info.town);
                            $("input[name='edit_status']").val(info.status);
            $("input[name='edit_AttorneyID']").val(providerID);
                            $("select[name='edit_status']").val(info.status);
                            $("select[name='edit_town']").val(info.town);
            $("#editAttorneyContainer").dialog({width: 600, title: "EDIT ATTORNEY:"});
        } else {
            $("<div />").dialog("An error has occured retrieving this attorney information.");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @wronisty, you're a star!! Want to submit the answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wroniasty said, it was my input should have been a select :)